# Setting iCloud Contacts to be the default contact directory in Outlook 2007

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, contacts, icloud

I am trying to set my iCloud Contacts folder in Outlook as the default folder for saving and reading contacts in Outlook 2007. I have already moved the folder up in the contacts list order and have set the iCloud contacts folder as the default sending contacts list for emails. Whenever I try to add a new contact to Outlook it always ends up in the regular Contacts folder, not the iCloud Contacts folder. I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to set the iCloud Contacts folder in Outlook as the default folder for creating contacts?

The system is a Windows 7 Dell Latitude with Office 2007.

Thanks!